# Checking a string against the user's password in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, authentication, passwords

I'm creating a system the provides users with access to a database where each user has an account with a password. For security reasons, I'd like to ensure that their password is not the same as the one they use to log in to Windows (server 2008 R2 with Windows 7 clients). I don't want to know every user's system password, rather just that the password they're trying to set is not identical to it.

Essentially, I'd like to be able to write a function that I can call it like so:

```
If IsSystemPassword(txtPass.Text) = False Then
  'hash password and save it to database
Else
  'return error and ask for new password
End If
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: wouldn't this be a massive security issue if any .net application could check a users windows password?

Comment: It likely would be, hence my research so far hasn't yielded anything. However, it must be something that someone's tried, so it was worth a go...

Comment: refer this post...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714679/how-get-current-username-and-password-from-windows-operating-system

Comment: well, perhaps windows deserves its reputation for being insecure :P

Comment: @pankeel that looks very promising, I'll take a look!

Comment: which type of this application? either it is window application or web application?

Comment: It's a VB.NET Windows Form Application.