# Windows user password verification

Tags: c#

I have a form in c# where I get the name and password of the user, I need to verify that what was typed in the textbox correpondem to the user logged in windows.

With

```
WindowsIdentity property ident = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent ();  
if (ident.Name == txtUsuario.Text)
{  
}
```

I can verify that the name matches.

But how do I check the password?

Comment: Ideally, you don't. Encouraging users to type in their passwords in anything that's not the secure desktop is bad practice. If you think you need the user's password, you're probably solving a problem the wrong way -- most things dealing with authentication will accept Kerberos tickets, impersonation or have some other way of verifying the user that does not involve you supplying a password, so the question would be why you think you need this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get Current Username and password from windows operating System.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714679/how-get-current-username-and-password-from-windows-operating-system)

Comment: Is the computer stand-alone or joined to a domain? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Hello friend, it will depend on each user, sometimes he can is in a domain and sometimes not. I need to check this because I need to log in to a windows service with the credentials of the user, if these credentials are wrong the service will get the default local user, and at the moment I am using sqllocaldb database that mono user, if the service has another user the auto level application does not rotate and vise versa.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Hello friend, see my answer to Camilo, any doubt I am willing.

Comment: You don't need the user's credentials to access an SQL LocalDB. You can use the `sqllocaldb share` function to share a user-specific LocalDB instance with other accounts (including service accounts). A better practice in this case would be to use a dedicated SQL Express instance, though (and grant permissions to both the service account and the user to access the database(s)).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, the sql server would be better but for the low user and install it alone and almost impossible, not to mention that heavy. Unfortunately in my country not everyone has a fast internet link, many users are discouraged by the delay.

Comment: LocalDB doesn't come with the operating system either, so the user is going to have to download something one way or another. If by "LocalDB" you don't actually mean SQL Server LocalDB but some other standalone database (like SQLite) it's another matter, but LocalDB is not particularly lightweight (it's a full SQL Server engine under the covers). If you *are* using a LocalDB, and the LocalDB in question is supposed to be used by your service only, then just have the service share its LocalDB instance with the user, so both accounts can access it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, it will only download the localdb which is a 30 MB, whereas the whole sql server with almost all the resources is 1.2 GB, when we click the localdb we do not have to configure a resource, we only install the mdf and ldf ie the database. That's the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: we should understand, are we in domain or not.

Step 2: validate credential by passing username and password.

Following references should be added into project

1) System.DirectoryServices (DLL)

2) System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (DLL)

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Validate username and password combination    
    ///     <para>Following Windows Services must be up</para>
    ///     <para>LanmanServer; TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">
    ///     Fully formatted UserName.
    ///     In AD: Domain + Username
    ///     In Workgroup: Username or Local computer name + Username
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="securePassword"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool ValidateUsernameAndPassword(string userName, SecureString securePassword)
    {
        bool result = false;

        ContextType contextType = ContextType.Machine;

        if (InDomain())
        {
            contextType = ContextType.Domain;
        }

        try
        {
            using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(contextType))
            {
                result = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(
                    userName, 
                    new NetworkCredential(string.Empty, securePassword).Password
                );
            }
        }
        catch (PrincipalOperationException)
        {
            // Account disabled? Considering as Login failed
            result = false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Validate: computer connected to domain?   
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///     True -- computer is in domain
    ///     <para>False -- computer not in domain</para>
    /// </returns>
    public static bool InDomain()
    {
        bool result = true;

        try
        {
            Domain domain = Domain.GetComputerDomain();
        }
        catch (ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why the dance via SecureString when it is extracted in clear-text anyway? Is it just for transport security?

Comment: Assuming that user enter his password in some form. It's unsafe to enter and store password as plain text. That is why we extract password only in last step, when it really needed

Comment: @Zam It doesn't make a difference when you do it if you do it. The `string` will stay in memory for noone-knows-how-long.

Comment: @Zam Hi friend, I'll try and give you the feedback.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i open for suggestions

Comment: If you could just explain a little your answer and not make it a dumped piece of code, that'll be just fine it seems

Comment: @Zam `ContextType.Machine` belongs to which library in web search can not find a dll to reference.

Comment: in your project you should add references to 1) `System.DirectoryServices` (DLL) and to 2) `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (DLL)

Comment: @Zam It worked perfectly, as I needed it. Thank you my friend.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It doesn't need any explanation. The function and variable names make it clear what everything is doing.